# How to resolve record not found error using cancan load_and_authorize_resource :product , :through => :current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a controller where I have

```
load_and_authorize_resource :product ,:through => :current_user

...

def set_user_product
  @user_product = User::Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

My `ability.rb` file contain

```
can :edit, User::Product do |product|
  product.try(:user) == user
end
```

Every thing looks ok but when I enter another user's product id in url I get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in User::ProductsController#edit

Completed 404 Not Found in 23ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User::Product with 'id'=<another_user_product_id> [WHERE `products`.`user` = ?]):
```

activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:336:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'

[image]

How can I resolve this error raised from cancan

Comment: use `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in controller

Comment: But id already exist and I want to show current user  cancan access denied error.